# What's the difference between @CreationTimestamp and @CreatedDate in Spring boot jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;
}
```

In Spring boot entity class
I don't know which one to use
What's the different?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Answer (score 11):

`@CreatedDate` is a Spring annotation and [covered in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/auditing.html#auditing.basics). It is applicable to all stores covered by Spring Data: JPA, JDBC, R2DBC, MongoDb, Cassandra and so on.

`@CreationTimestamp` is a Hibernate annotation [covered in the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-CreationTimestamp). It is applicable to Hibernate only.

As far as what they actually do they are pretty much the same with the Spring variant supporting more data types.